# Neo4J - Multiple node results into single row Using Python

Tags: python, list, neo4j, nodes, transformation

I am currently running through the process of upgrading my relational database into a Neo4J database. So far, I have been able to surpass everything I originally was designing in the relational database (MySQL). That is, until it comes time to make my reports.

I am using Python in order to query the database and I can return all the relevant information, but not in the manner I would like.

Code:

```
AList = session.run("match (dept:Department)<-[]-(d1:Domain)<-[]-(d2:Domain)<-[]-(a:TestAnswer)-[]->(q:SurveyQuestion) return dept.ABBR as Department, d1.DomainName as Forest, d2.DomainName as Domain, q.QuestionDesc as Question, a.Result as Answer ORDER BY Department")
```

This returns a wonderful list of nodes, sorted by the department's abbreviation, that has an answer for each of the questions asked.

Example of current output:

> Department|    Forest| Domain| Question|   Answer|
>
> Dname| ForestLocation| DomainName| Q1| 90|
>
> Dname| ForestLocation| DomainName| Q2| 1|

etc.

I would like to recreate this to have the following layout, but I'm not entirely sure if I have to go through a lengthy process in python 3 or if I can use some form of union within Neo4j to achieve the most simplistic result:

> Department | Forest | Domain | Q1 | Q2
>
> Dname| ForestName | DomainName | 90 | 1

Any assistance would be appreciated - or if someone could point me in the right direction on where I could find the answers, that would also be helpful.

Thank you for your time,
Jim

Comment: As far as I know Neo4j can't provide dynamic columns, but if you know the questions you want to use as columns ahead of time, you should be able to do this. However, your title indicates that all you need is to get all this on a single row, I'm assuming for each Department/Forest/Domain. Do you really need separate columns per question, or is it enough to aggregate questions and answers to a single row by some other means?

Comment: @InverseFalcon If I could make it into its own iterator/list, then I could print it out using the print command into a CSV to mimic the original table created by the report (With hard coded headers). This would be an acceptable solution - how could I reach this conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, dynamic columns aren't supported in Neo4j as far as I can tell. That said, there are ways to aggregate results so you'll get a single row for each Department/Forest/Domain, and group the questions and answers for later iteration when processing that row.

Here's the Cypher that should help you out, using [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) to collect the questions and answers:

```
match (dept:Department)<--(d1:Domain)<--(d2:Domain)
with dept, d1, d2, 
 [(d2)<--(a:TestAnswer)-->(q:SurveyQuestion) | {Question:q.QuestionDesc, Answer:a.Result}] as answeredQuestions
return dept.ABBR as Department, d1.DomainName as Forest, d2.DomainName as Domain, answeredQuestions 
ORDER BY Department
```